# How can I grant permissions in Google Cloud Platform by using-- gcloud beta spanner databases command?

Tags: gcloud

I can see
`gcloud beta spanner databases execute-sql [MY_DATABASE_ID] --instance=[MY_INSTANCE_ID] --sql='SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE MyKey = 1'`

for executing dcl like -
`GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON database.* TO 'user'@'cloudsqlproxy~%'"..`
is there a gcloud command ?

Answer (score 1):

Cloud Spanner is not a normal SQL database like MySQL and PostgreSQL. While queries use SQL, user and data manipulation does not.

To give a user account access to a database, you need to use IAM:

```
gcloud beta spanner databases add-iam-policy-binding [MY_DATABASE_ID] \
    --instance=[MY_INSTANCE_ID] --member="user:email1@gmail.com" \
    --role="roles/spanner.databaseAdmin"
```

You can find more information on managing spanner from gcloud at https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/gcloud-spanner.

---

cloudsql-proxy only works for Cloud SQL. For Spanner, you will need to use one of the client libraries: https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/reference/libraries.

Comment: Thanks. I could use "gcloud beta sql connect [instance] --user=root" and was able to grant privileges

Comment: That isn't Cloud Spanner. That is Cloud SQL. That being said, it sounds like you really want to be using Cloud SQL anyways.